# AppleScript can't find image in Users Library folder

Tags: applescript

I'm new to AppleScript and i'm trying to figure this out.

I'm trying to add an attachment for an email and **I can get** the image with

```
tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:"/Users/jarrod/Library/img/image.png"} at after the last paragraph
```

but I want the script to be dynamic and work on other computers so I tried

```
tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:"~/Library/img/image.png"} at after the last paragraph
```

but it **can't** find the image...

If I paste the path and search for it in my browser it comes up... 
~/Library/img/image.png

Someone please tell me why this isn't working or if you know of a work around to get to the users folder name in AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a path like this:

```
set myPath to POSIX path of (path to library folder from user domain) & "img/image.png"
```

Comment: Works perfectly! If I had more votes I would give you an Vote Up as well!